# What is the equivalent of .Net Double.PositiveInfinity in C++WinRT?

Tags: winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

If at all there is. And if not, what should be passed to functions like

```
var tb = new TextBlock { Text = "Text", FontSize = 10 };
tb.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
```

Comment: Since a `Size` stores two `float` values you might want to try [`numeric_limits<float>::infinity()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity). That's an awkward value, though, so I guess `numeric_limits<float>::max()` would be a more natural value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the [C++/WinRT projection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/) is to let you use Windows Runtime APIs from 'Standard C++'. Always start with who the C++17 Standard would have you do it.

```
#include <cmath>

// std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
// std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
```

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/INFINITY)

> There is a drop-list on many Microsoft Doc pages which let you set the examples to C++/WinRT instead of C#:

> [image: Selecting W++/WinRT]

Comment: Thanks Chuck. This is helpful, I have used the drop-list to see examples of C++WinRT instead of C# and there are many cases where those example are missing. I am filing that feedback on the page.